# Why doesn't visual studio recognize my source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm running into an issue where visual studio 2015 is saying that it can't find the definition for an object. The class that it refers too is in the project so I'm not sure why it can't find it. It's not in the project directory, but it's one outside of it. The visual studio solution is in Project1. The code files are in source and header files respectively. I keep getting this error

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DataCenter<float>::DataCenter<float>(void)" (??0?$DataCenter@M@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main Project1
```

I've uploaded a copy of my folder to google drive here: [ProjectDataCenter](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1PZNPc8PSbXT21nR1ZRVGxFMGs&usp=sharing)

Do you know what I would have to do to get this to link correctly?

**Edit:**
According to [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

*"Under MSVS, files added to a project automatically have their object files linked together and a lib file would be generated (in common usage)"*

The files that are not linking are in the same project and thus there should not be any missed dependencies.

Comment: As you have a template it seems @Jonathan had selected the wrong duplicate (though IIRC the case is covered there also). I'll mark the right one.

Comment: Anyone care to comment on where this answer is in the "duplicate" post because I don't see it at all

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had put more context in your question.

Comment: Ah. of course. Thank you.

Comment: The dupe I closed with covers this too; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574417#12574417